# Angularjs Syntax error on dynamic validation of controls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application using angularjs. I am generating input controls randomly. I am validating above controls but i am facing some errors.

```
 <div class="upload-button" ng-repeat="fileInput in fileInputs" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((formDoc.$submitted && formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$invalid )|| (formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$invalid && formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$dirty))}">
                            <div >
                                <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$dirty && formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$invalid ">
                                    <span ng-show="formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$invalid && formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$dirty">*{{'Required Numeric Value' | translate}}</span>
                                </span>
                                <div class="upload-button-icon">
                                    <img src="images/folder-small.png">
                                    <div class="upload-text">{{fileInput.Filename}}</div>
                                    <div ng-if="fileInput.Filepath == ''">
                                        <input type="file" file-data="{{fileInput.Filename}}" file-model="{{fileInput.Filename}}" id="file_input_id" name="{{fileInput.Fileid}}" required valid-file ng-model="file" />
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am getting proper output as expected. In console i am getting below errors.

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is not a valid identifier at column 49 of the expression [{ 'has-error' : ((formDoc.$submitted && formDoc..$invalid )|| (formDoc..$invalid && formDoc..$dirty))}] starting at [.$invalid )|| (formDoc..$invalid && formDoc..$dirty))}].
```

and

```
angular.js:12416 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is not a valid identifier at column 9 of the expression [formDoc..$dirty && formDoc..$invalid] starting at [.$dirty && formDoc..$invalid].
```

Below is my js code.

```
function filldocs(ReqDocs)
            {
                if (ReqDocs != null)
                    {
                var str = ReqDocs;
                var array = str.split(',');
                var arr = [];
                var arrayLength = array.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    arr.push({
                        Filename: array[i],
                        Fileid: "FileInput"+i,
                        Filepath: ""
                    })
                }
                $scope.fileInputs = arr;
                }
            }
```

I am not able to figure it out what i am missing in the above code! May i get some help to identify the above error? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your data for `fileInputs` it seems like some of them don't have the field `Fileid`. Hence why it's outputting as `formDoc..$invalid`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my code.

Comment: I'm afraid it must be something else causing this error as it's [working fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/s57mvc23/2/) (As in I get no errors)

Comment: I commented second span and worked fine...

Comment: Even with the spans, [all is good](https://jsfiddle.net/s57mvc23/3/)

Comment: It worked. I do not know what caused error?

Answer (score 0):

You've got double decimal points happening. Check the code that is generating the html.
e.g

```
   formDoc..$invalid
```

looks like it should be

```
formDoc.$invalid
```

Comment: Thank you. I  do not have ... <div class="upload-button ng-scope" ng-repeat="fileInput in fileInputs" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((formDoc.$submitted &amp;&amp; formDoc.FileInput0.$invalid )|| (formDoc.FileInput0.$invalid &amp;&amp; formDoc.FileInput0.$dirty))}">

Comment: The error message says that you do. How exactly are you generating the controls randomly?

Answer (score 0):

The `fileInput.Fileid` is empty. So you got the double points at `formDoc..$invalid`.
Double points are not a valid identifier.

Comment: Obviouly they are empty. That's why there is nothing between the points. `formDoc.{{fileInput.Fileid}}.$invalid`